# Sum of Brownian motion and gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

> Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion. Let $X_t:=e^{-t}B_{e^{2t}}$ and therefore is $N(0,1)$ distributed with $X_0=B_1$. I wanna prove that $\int_0^tX_sds$ is normally distributed too.

I see that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_{kt/n} \to \int_0^tX_sds.$$

Then in the proof that I'm following is written that $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^nX_{kt/n}$ is a Gaussian process but I'm not able to understand why. I would agree if the we have a sum of independent normally distributed random variable, but in this case it is not. So why it is a gaussian process?

my attempt is the following:$\sum_{k=1}^nX_{kt/n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \big( \sum_{i=0}^tX_{\frac{k(i+1)}{n}}-X_{\frac{k(i)}{n}}  \big) +(B_1-B_0)$ where $B_0=0$ and in this way I have a sum of independent normally distributed random variable.

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of "Gaussian process"?

Comment: @NateEldredge I provide my attempt on the question. A gaussian process is a process that for very $ t vec(X_{t_1},..X_{t_n}) is  multivariate normally distributed.

Comment: Are you aware of the following fact: given any random vector $\mathbf{X}$ which is multivariate normally distributed, and any linear map $T$ of appropriate dimension, the random vector $T \mathbf{X}$ is also multivariate normally distributed?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I knew that but it seems to me that in this case X is not a multivariate normal. Is just one dimensional

Comment: I think the point is that, for each fixed $n$, the random vector $(X_{t/n}, X_{2t/n}, \dots, X_{t})$ is multivariate normal.  Therefore, applying the linear map $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ results in a normal random variable.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes this is right but then I have to prove that the random vector $(X_{t/n}. . . X_t)$ is multivariate normal, and for doing so I have to refer to my attempt of the proof, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: The fact that $(X_{t/n}, \dots, X_t)$ is multivariate normal follows directly from the fact that the Brownian motion $B_t$ is a Gaussian process, and so therefore any $(B_{t_1}, \dots, B_{t_n})$ is multivariate normal (with a covariance that is not the identity!).  Apply this with $t_k = e^{-2kt/n}$ and note that $(X_{t/n}, \dots, X_t)$ is a (diagonal) linear transformation of the result.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

That $(X_t)_t$ is a Gaussian process does not mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, as you claim. But the increments are independent, so I can say that $D_{21} = X_2 - X_1$ is independent of $X_1$, and so
$$
X_1 + X_2 = X_1 + \left(X_1 + D_{21}\right) = 2X_1 + D_{21}, 
$$
which is a sum of zero-mean normally distributed random variables, and hence itself is a zero-mean normal.

**UPDATE**

In a similar way, note that
$$
\begin{split}
X_1 + X_2 + X_3
 &= X_1 + X_2 + (X_2 + D_{32}) \\
 &= X_1 + 2X_2 + D_{32} \\
 &= X_1 + 2(X_1 + D_{21}) + D_{32} \\
 &= 3X_1 + D_{21} + D_{32}.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: what I did is the following: $\sum_{k=1}^nX_{kt/n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \big( \sum_{i=0}^tX_{\frac{k(i+1)}{n}}-X_{\frac{k(i)}{n}}  \big) -(B_1-B_0)$ where $B_0=0$ and in this way I have a sum of independent normally distributed random variable.

Comment: @Alias__ the idea is right, but I think some details may not be. See update to my answer.

Comment: I see that following your approach I have a constant equal to the number of term that I'm summing that multiply the first term ($X_1$) but I don't see the mistake on my attempt: $\sum_{k=1}^n \big( \sum_{i=0}^{t-1}X_{\frac{k(i+1)}{n}}-X_{\frac{k(i)}{n}}  \big) +(B_1-B_0) = \sum_{k=1}^n \big( X_{\frac{kt}{n}}-X_0 \big) +(B_1-B_0)$ by telescopic series and then $\sum_{k=1}^n X_{\frac{kt}{n}}-B_1 +(B_1-B_0) =\sum_{k=1}^nX_{\frac{kt}{n}}$

Comment: please, let me know if there is some mistake.

Comment: @Alias__ sorry just checked, looks ok